# How to show event dots in fs calendar from an array

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, fscalendar

I'm using fs calendar and i'm trying to set event dots from an array named dates. this array has event dates in it that are saved in string form. so i have to convert each index to date and then set an event dot for that date.
here is my attempt to do so:

```
if dates.isEmpty == false {
    func calendar(_calendar: FSCalendar!, hasEventForDate dateFormatter: DateFormatter) -> Bool {
    for i in 0...dates.count - 1 {
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter ()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy/MM/dd"
        dateFormatter.locale = Locale.init(identifier: "fa_IR")

        dateFormatter.date(from: dates[i])

        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy/MM/dd"

        return true
    }
    return false

}
}
```

but nothing happens and there is no event dot when i compile the code. what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**First** recommendation, use a dictionary instead of array of dates, is less demanding to lookup dates in a dictionary

**Second** if you need use values in an array then you should use **for** **in** and use objects directly, not index to get objects in the original array, also declare the date formatter only once

**Third** you need use `func calendar(_ calendar: FSCalendar, numberOfEventsFor date: Date) -> Int` **because** `func calendar(_calendar: FSCalendar!, hasEventForDate dateFormatter: DateFormatter) -> Bool` is deprecated

**Try with this code**

```
func calendar(_ calendar: FSCalendar, numberOfEventsFor date: Date) -> Int {
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy/MM/dd"
    dateFormatter.locale = Locale.init(identifier: "fa_IR")

    for dateStr in dates{
        if(dateFormatter.string(from: date) == dateStr)
        {
            return 1
        }
    }
    return 0
}
```